# How to have color in your blend file preview

Tags: blend-files, file-browser

So I am suffering from a TREMENDOUS amount of Blender files! I currently have about 1000 on my machine and organizing these in certain folders helps a little but it does not really solve the issue. I kept thinking I really need to get color in these grey previews and then one day I spotted this ...

[image]

One file in hundreds just randomly has a little bit of color ... I have since tried everything to recreate this result somehow but have failed and I was just curious if anyone knew how to make these file previews colorful and easier on the eyes.

Thank you !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *File Browser* preview only shows solid view colors.
You have three options here:

- Adjust the solid view color for each material (in Material tab)
- Set solid view color for each object (in Object tab)
- Use random color for each object

You can switch between different modes using the Viewport Shading menu.

[image]

Comment: DING DING DING! We have a winner!!

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Happy to help, enjoy your colorful file library :).