# How can I get a colored preview of all the blend files in the file browser?

Tags: rendering, image, blend-files, file-browser

Some of my blend file previews are shaded and colored. Most of them are just solid shaded:

[image]

[image]

How can I get a colored, nice shaded preview for all of my files?

fyi: i am using a mac...so a "windows only" solution won't help me.

Comment: did you color them in the Material > Viewport Display?

Comment: Äh…no…cause I didn’t know 

Comment: That's a really good question. I really don't know, I only know it has neither to do with the Shading Mode in the moment you are saving the file, nor if the material has a given color for Viewport Display, so that it looks colored in Solid Mode. Or if any of these factors have an influence, I cannot willingly decide what I want to see in the thumbnail by changing any of these settings.

Comment: @moonboots: Gordon is right. Viewport display doesn't work :( or do i have to set something special?

Comment: If I give a color in Viewport Display, the file icon will display a color when I'll try to open it, but it may not be what you're expecting

Comment: @moonboots: i want a colored preview of my blend file as shown in my pictures. Not just a colored icon ;)

Comment: I mean the object is colored like that: https://zupimages.net/up/21/26/ccwx.jpg

Comment: äh...possible duplicate ‍♂️. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170712/how-to-have-color-in-your-blend-file-preview

Comment: the answer you link cites the Viewport Display color, not sure what he meant with Random color though, it doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: i am just trying...but his answers seem to work...

Comment: so that was my answer as well  ^^  Material > Viewport Display

Comment: @moonboots: yes, but you "forgot" to mention that the material shouldn't use nodes... ;)

Comment: mmh, works with nodes for me...

Comment: if you once put the nodes to "not use nodes" and put them on again - then he "kind of" shows the colors from "before" -> the behaviour is a bit weird....but if you "use nodes" at once you won't see any color. Just try out with default cube, use nodes, give color and save.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand but OK  ;)

Comment: if you are really interested i can make a yt video to show you ;)

Comment: I don't think the _Use Nodes_ is important, I figured out an answer though it might not yet be the complete "magic" behind this all...

Answer (score 1):

EEVEE:

You get colors in the preview, if your objects have materials which don't use nodes (this is the case when the "use nodes" button isn't checked).

[image]

or if you choose a color in material -> viewport display. Then this color will be shown in the preview.

But...there must be some other possibilities, because i see more colored previews with different settings...

If once set your materials to "not use nodes" and the preview was colored, you can set them back to "use nodes" and the previews will stay colored.

Ok, one new "rule" i found out:
If you uncheck "use nodes" and set a color, this color will be used in the preview.
If you then check "use nodes" it still will use the color of the "unchecked nodes" color in the preview.

Comment: That seems odd... as if the thumbnail preview is saved at some time and doesn't get refreshed - or refreshed at some (random?) intervals. Does this mean if I change the objects in the scene, the thumbnail won't show that either? Well, switching all materials to not use nodes to have colored thumbnails is definitely not worth the effort for me, if that's the solution :D

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: The preview will be refreshed whenever you move/add a mesh object (i just tried) but the colors won't. So i think i you start a new blend file, this might be a solution. For old blend files...for sure not ;) I am also not sure whether it is a bug because it's seem to be weird...

Comment: This "Use Nodes" option is not available in Cycles, so to get your Cycles file colored in thumbnail there must be another way.

Comment: oh sorry, yeah, i just tried out eevee so far. i will adapt my answer

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this seems tricky. The linked answer to the other question here is only "half the truth". The following I found out for both *Eevee* and *Cycles*, although it seems like @Chris pointed out, that option 2. below is not working on Mac, only Windows.

In the *Viewport Shading* settings you can use the following three *Color* options if you want a colored thumbnail preview:

1. **Material**: This will show the color you've set under *Viewport Display* in the *Material Properties*.
2. **Object**: Enabling this will show the color under *Viewport Display* in the *Object Properties*.
3. **Texture**: Now here comes the tricky part - if you choose *Texture*, the thumbnail will show the last *Image Texture* you've selected in the Material. If you select some other *Texture Node* like e.g. *Musgrave*, then the preview will show the *Viewport Display* color from the *Material Properties*.  My guess is, this texture preview doesn't work with procedural textures, only image textures. Also it will always show the image mapped to the UVs at scale 1, no matter if you use other texture coordinates or maybe scale it up or down.

That said, there is still room for further investigation I suppose but that's a first approach on getting colored thumbnails where you can decide what colors you want there.

[image: thumb options]

And here how it turns out using **Material** (the object on the right has two different materials):

[image: thumb_material]

I've chosen different colors in the *Object Properties* so this is how it looks if I switch to **Object**:

[image: thumb_object]

And if I now switch to **Texture** and there is an *Image Texture* selected or you select one afterwards, at first this image is shown on the UVs of the object. And the preview won't change if you select the *Mix RGB* or *Texture Coordinate* notes afterwards:

[image: thumb_texture1]

However, if you select a node which is found under the *Add* > *Texture* menu in the *Node Editor* (in this example the *Musgrave* texture), the shading preview will now show the *Viewport Display* color set under *Material Properties*:

[image: thumb_texture2]

Here are the thumbnails:

[image: thumbnails]

Comment: sorry, but point 2 does not work  -> preview won't change its color. Your answer sounds like "if you change to object your preview will take the color of object properties -> viewport display" but it does not. It always take the color for the material -> viewport display

Comment: It works. If you change the _Viewport Shading Color_ to _Object_, the thumbnail will change its color if you have set a color in the _Object Properties_.

Comment: not in my version. 3.0.0 alpha on mac

Comment: Well, I base my answers on stable official releases to make sure you're it's not subject to change... unless I want to point out differences between official and experimental releases. And if the problem depends on the Mac version, I only have Windows so I can't try that, sorry.

Comment: and 2.92 doesn't work too

Comment: I've edited my thumbnails in to show it working... I've tried 3.0.0 Alpha and it works there, too. Maybe it's Mac-related? I mean, Windows has its own thumbnails system so maybe they are in a way different that make it not work under Mac? But anyway, since you have _Material_ and _Texture_ there are still options to get your thumbs colored.

Comment: i believe you that it is working for windows...but it doesn't work on Mac. That's all i can tell.